# php http request to get .text response

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

Is it possible to access a file(.txt) in server 'B'  as a response of http request send from server 'A' using php? can u please specify the 'response-type' of http request for the same?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do yu want to download a file or display its content?

Comment: Its unclear the problem, pls edit your question and give more info.

Comment: If you are running a GET request, then you don't need this fluffy header.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly (that would be a huge securityrisk).

But if you have a script on server B that honors requests from server A it can be as simple as:

Server A request: [here](http://www.exampleserverB.com/getfile.php?filename=whatever.txt)

And then from server B you simply pick up that file and return it (with appropriate headers if you like).

But make VERY sure you don't allow any name. I advise you to restrict the requests to certain directories. Why? Because you don't want funny filenames reaching out of the assigned directories.

Addition: [here](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

That is a helpful function to get the content.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether the requesting server is whitelisted...such approach shouldn't be encouraged. High risk.

Comment: I don't agree. As long as you check the file is in a directory you allow, the risk is reduced to reading files in THAT directory, and such checks aren't hard.